# Need to parse out different types of text data from an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-recognition, google-vision

I'm doing a hobby project, where I will analyze a question of

> "What does it take to win a match in Team Fortress 2?"

[Team Fortress 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Fortress_2)(TF2) is my all-time favorite Online FPS video game by Valve, which was released over 13 years ago but still boasting +100K weekly players. I spent countless hours enjoying TF2 related contents from different TF2 communities, and thought I'd give it back by doing what I do well, analyzing data.

My plan is to first gather datasets on game stats. The unit of an analysis will be at a match (a round in a game, which usually consists of 5~6 matches) level, and for each match I will manually record if a match was won or lost, and how quick a match was finished (of course normalized: say the maximum allowed time is 30 min for map X, and the game was finished in 15 min, so this match will have 15/30). Also for every match I will make different observations within a game and manually record them in a spreadsheet because there is no other way to collect such data.

From my initial analysis based on number of players in TF2, I would need around 100 matches for each map (I plan to do 5 most played maps) to reach a statistical significance to be able to generalize the learnings. So that would be around 500 matches, which is a lot, yes! But since there is no other way I will do this.

However, I realized there are some information(attributes) that I can get about every match from a screenshot (example attached below). I put squared-boxes with red border around the stuff that I need from the screenshot.

Here are some more details:

- I need the name of the side I am on, which in this case is "BLU"
- I need the number of players in this team, which is "8"
- Also you can see the first long vertical red box, which represents scores of each player, and I need to Sum this number. Say there are 8 players, and each player scored 10 points each, so it would be 8*10 = 80
- Another long vertical red box next to the scores shows icons of each player, and each icon represents 1 of 9 different classes (i.e. Heavy, medic, spy, etc.) a player can choose within a game. Obviously there are only 9 icons, and there are available mappings of icon to class name. I want to ingest this data and create 9 different attributes for a match, each representing proportion of classes. For example, in a match with a total of 8 people in "BLU" team, 2 of them were medics, so something like "proportion_of_medics": 2/8
- Also server name and map names at the bottom

As you can see, there are two sources of attributes that describe each match: My manual labor + screenshots from every match (at the end, so the scores are not 0). Because these are screenshots on a pre-defined UI on a fixed resolution (1980*1080 in this case), the locations of pixels that contain the info that I need is fixed.

Another big caveat is that as you can see in the screenshot, there are two places where information is contained, one for "BLU" team, and one for "RED" team. A player can only belong to 1 of the 2 teams for a match, and can only see class information of other players only if they are on the same team (in another words, you can not see what classes your opposing team has picked), and the team you're in is indicated by your own ID getting highlighted with a gray box (in the screenshot, my ID is "Team Fortress 2", and you can see the hue around my ID is different than the rest), so what this all means is that if I'm in a "BLU" team, the info I need is on the left side, and if on "RED" team, than it will be on the right side.

From my initial assumptions, it doesn't seem too complicated to write a Python script using some library to get this thing done, but due to some of the complicating details I mentioned above, I'm not sure if it can be done quickly. If it's gonna be too much, then I will just manually go through each screenshot.

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting project, but I am not sure if it fits stackoveflow really well. My advice to you is to use an OCR on the boxes containing text and some pattern matching for the class detection.

Comment: @Lescurel - Thank you! I plan to make a video and upload it on YouTube, hope I can finish the project soon and share it. Anyways, yeah OCR with Pytesseract and OpenCV looks promising. I was first looking at Google Vision AI, but OCR was the term I was looking for. I will definitely play around with it, but my concern is that I'm not the best coder, so writing the logics that work-around all the complicating details I mentioned in the original post, might actually take me say, X amount of hours, but if I can go through 500 screenshots and record the data in less than that, I'd just do that.